# Git Merge conflict - detached HEAD master

Tags: git

Newbie trying to fix merge conflict on gitlab

Have performed a merge request on gitlab and it says there are conflicts and advises the following to resolve:

```sh
git fetch origin
git checkout -b "docker" "origin/docker"

git fetch origin
git checkout "origin/master"
git merge --no-ff "docker"

git push origin "master"
```

I already have a local branch named docker that I merged previously into master. Since that time I have push further changes to remote *origin/docker* and hence the second merge request.  So I issue a `git checkout -b "newdocker" "origin/docker"`

When I do a git checkout origin/master it says that it is in detached HEAD state?? ``git status``` shows the message:

```sh
=HEAD detached at origin/master
You have unmerged paths.
  (fix conflicts and run "git commit")
  (use "git merge --abort" to abort the merge)

Changes to be committed:
        new file:   .gitlab-ci.yml
        new file:   .npmignore
        modified:   INSTALL.sh
        modified:   README.md
        modified:   package.json

Unmerged paths:
  (use "git add <file>..." to mark resolution)
        both added:      Makefile
        both modified:   docker/README.md
        both added:      docker/docker-compose.ci.yml
        both modified:   tests/e2e/jest.config.js
        both modified:   tests/jest.config.js
```

Following the instructions, when I issue *git merge --no-ff newdocker* I get notified of conflicts. I then modify the files to accept incoming changes and commit.

```sh
git add .
git commit
```

git displays a message recognising that I am commiting a merge, confirming the files changed.
If I then do `git push origin master` it says everything is up-to-date.

`git status` in a terminal then shows

```sh
~/Development/Projects/plugin  ➦ 28a5cd8  git status
HEAD detached from origin/master
nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

Is there any way of resolving this or is it easier just to create a new repository?

What is the safest set of steps to merge my docker branch into master to resolve merge conflicts? The steps suggested by GitLab.com are:

```sh
git fetch origin
git checkout "origin/master"
git merge --no-ff "docker"
```

**Update**
Got it working with the help of those that commented. Many thanks!! The problem as suggested in the comments was the command `git checkout "origin/master"` which originated from the gitlab.com dialog box that suggested how to resolve merge conflicts. Have raised a [documentation issue] with gitlab.com reporting this.

The steps that allowed me to do the merge as suggested in comments was:

```
# checkout the local master branch
git checkout master

# merge the local docker branch
git merge docker

# resolve conflicts by modifying and saving conflicting source files to # accept necessary changes and then..
git add .
git commit
git push origin master
```

Comment: You shouldn't `git checkout "origin/master"`, as you can't *check out* a remote branch. Doing this will check out a detached HEAD at the same commit. Instead you should check out `master` (your local copy), and update it from `origin/master`. You can push arbitrary commits to a remote branch, but I do not recommend it.

Comment: Thanks newbie at this. Do you mean, git checkout master, git pull origin master? Tried that and it works for both my master and docker branch. So what are the steps to follow to merge my docker branch into master?

Comment: to merge X into Y: `git checkout Y` followed by `git merge X`, you have to check out the *target* branch and merge (from) the *source* branch. So for your branches it would be `git checkout master` followed by `git merge docker`.

Comment: That did the trick cheers, many thanks :) ....now am in the situation where somebody else has suggested the same solution. Do you want to write your comment as an answer and have it accepted?

Comment: Not at all, Lmtx left an excellent answer.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can try `git push origin master --force` if you are sure that state in your local master branch is the proper one and you want to update origin to meet it.

https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push#Documentation/git-push.txt---force

## update

try following:

```
git checkout master
git checkout -b master_backup
git switch -
git reset --hard origin/master
```

check local files, if needed compare with versions in `master_backup` branch

## update 2

In order to merge your changes execute:

```
git checkout master
git merge master_backup
```

or

```
git checkout master
git merge docker
```

depending on which branch you actually want to merge into master

Comment: Thanks for responding @Imtx. Gave it a try then did git fetch origin and git checkout origin/master and it remains in detached HEAD state. When I did the push git gave a message saying that everything was up-to-date. It is looking like I might have to create a new repository perhaps...

Comment: @anon_dcs3spp please check my update and let me know if it worked

Comment: The detached HEAD state is because git won't "check out" remote branches. Doing this will simply check out the same commit as a detached HEAD. If you want to check out a branch you should check out your local master, or check out a new branch referencing the same commit, but `git checkout origin/whatever` will never check out a branch.

Comment: Thanks @lmtx tried that and my local master branch is upto date but it is still unmerged. It is the current unmerged version. How do I merge my docker branch into master?

Comment: Thanks @lmtx, much appreciated for all who helped me and suggested solutions :) it did the trick and saved creating another repository